# Why I can't create a class named "Case" on PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

```
class Case {
// class body
}
```

It's because the "Case" word is reserved by the switch statement? Workarounds? Ideas?

Comment: Use another word?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: Without more description on what a case is/does we are pretty limitied on how best to

Comment: You can use "Caso", it's case in Spanish!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `case` is the [reserved word](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Reserved words can not be used as constants, function names, class names and etc. Try to avoid that.

Comment: The reserved word is 'case' not 'Case', so I would expect the name 'Case' to be a valid class name.

Comment: @Kwebble Reserved words are case insensitive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624257/are-php-keywords-case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a reserved word.  Just rename your class.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a list of reserved words: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

These can't be used in the way you're trying, ie as constants, class names, function or method names.

No way around it, and no real work arounds. Pear naming convention is OK though, Folder_Folder_Case wouldn't cause any problems.